# Google Chart draw issue

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, angular-directive, redraw

I'm building an Area Chart with Google Charts.

I made the chart as an angular directive. It works well (most of the time).

Sometimes when the page loads the chart is not drawn as it should look (see image below)

[image]

**This is how I get the data for the chart:**

```
Chart.getHistoricalEstimates(scope.guid, lsUser)
    .then(function(results) {
      angular.extend(scope, {
        estimates: results,
        loaded: true
      });
    }, function(err) {
      scope.error = err;
    });
```

So my service called "Chart", when the data is ready the value of `loaded` is set to true.

Inside my directive, i watch the `loaded` scope:

`scope.$watch('loaded', onChartReady);`

and call this function:

```
function onChartReady(nVal) {
 if (nVal === true) {
   drawChart()
     .then(function(data) {
       angular.element($window).triggerHandler('resize');
     });
 }
```

}

The `drawChart` functions is set up as promise `$q`:

```
function drawChart() {
    return $q(function(resolve) {
      pureData = scope.estimates.pure;
      chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(chartElement);

      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(scope.estimates.labelled);
      var options = {
        pointShape: 'circle',
        pointSize: 12,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        seriesType: 'area',
        interpolateNulls: true,
        legend: 'none',
        ...
      };

      chart.draw(data, options);

      $timeout(function() {
        resolve();
      }, 0, true);
    });
  }
```

**And finally this is how the DOM element looks:**

```
<area-chart
  ng-if="estimates"
  chart-data="estimates">
</area-chart>
```

As I mentioned, the chart works most of the time, but sometimes still displays as the first image shows. Apparently I can force the issue when I open the page in a new tab.

Comment: i've seen similar results when the chart is drawn _before_ the html container is visible, would that be a possibility here?

Comment: It _could_ be, but it shouldn't be the issue to be honest. I've done everything (that I know of) to make sure the chart is drawn after the html is loaded.

Comment: not necessarily loaded, but visible and not hidden -- otherwise, using specific `height` and `width` in chart options should fix...

Comment: @WhiteHat what if it should be responsive?